# Dynamically creating checkboxes that are bound to an observable inside an observable array isn't working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, checkbox, knockout.js

I've been playing around with KnockoutJS in order to gain a better understanding of how it works, which eventually leads to some unconventional coding.

This is the script:

```
var ViewModel = function() {
    var self = this;

    self.counter = ko.observable(0);
    self.someFruits = ko.observableArray();

    self.createbox = function (){
        var value = {
            name: self.counter(),
            isChecked: ko.observable(true)
        };

        self.someFruits.push(value);

        $("#div1").append('<div><input type="checkbox" data-bind="checked: someFruits()[' + self.counter() + '].isChecked" /> Cherry</div>');

        $("#div2").append('<div><input type="checkbox" data-bind="checked: someFruits()[' + self.counter() + '].isChecked" /> Cherry</div>');

        self.counter(self.counter() + 1);
    }
};

ko.applyBindings(new ViewModel());
```

And here is the HTML:

```
<div>
    <div>
        <button data-bind="click: createbox" type="button" class="btn btn-warning">Create Box</button>
    </div>

    <div id="div1">
    </div>
    <br>
    <br>
    <div id="div2">
    </div>
</div>
```

What I'm trying to simulate is the functionality to dynamically create check-boxes that will be data-bound to an observable object inside an observable-array. So I made a button that will `push` a new object that will contain a `ko.observable` into an `observableArray`. Then use Jquery to append HTML markups to create new checkboxes. I append two identical checkboxes each time to different `div` just to see if they are updating according to the bound object.

It is brutish, and ideally, I shouldn't use JQuery for these purposes, and perhaps a `foreach` would be nice here. But I'd still like to understand why this isn't working when I thought it should.

EDIT: For example, if I click the button 3 times, 3 checkboxes will be created for each `div`, making it a total of 6 checkboxes in the enitre page. If I check the first checkbox in the first `id=div1`, then the first checkbox in `id=div2` should also update equally. I've been using JSFiddle to test this, and the checkboxes won’t automatically update when its counterpart is clicked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In knockout, you rarely have to append/ remove things from the UI using jquery. Your `viewModel` should control all the adding, removing or any kind of DOM manipulation. In your case, you are pushing to `someFruits` observableArray. Use [`foreach`](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/foreach-binding.html) binding to display them.

So, in the below snippet, I have added an input to add new fruits. Also, a [computed](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/computedObservables.html) property which displays the "checked" fruits as and when you change the checkboxes.

```js
var ViewModel = function() {
  var self = this;
  self.fruitName = ko.observable();
  self.someFruits = ko.observableArray([]);

  self.createbox = function() {
    self.someFruits.push({
      name: self.fruitName(),
      isChecked: ko.observable(true)
    });

    // clear the input after a fruit is added
    self.fruitName('');
  }

  // every time "someFruits" or "isChecked" changes this gets computed again
  self.checkedFruits = ko.computed(function() {
    return self.someFruits()
      .filter(a => a.isChecked())
      .map(b => b.name);
  })
};

ko.applyBindings(new ViewModel());
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.2/knockout-min.js"></script>
<div>
  <div>
    <input data-bind="value: fruitName" />
    <button data-bind="click: createbox" type="button" class="btn btn-warning">Create Box</button>
  </div>

  <div id="div1" data-bind="foreach:someFruits">
    <div>
      <input type="checkbox" data-bind="checked: isChecked" />
      <span data-bind="text: name"></span>
    </div>
  </div>
  <br> Selected fruits:

  <span data-bind="text: checkedFruits"></span>
</div>
```

Click on `Run Code snippet` to test it out. [Here's a fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/p3zzgm24/) if you want to play around with it. If you're learning knockout, I think it's better to not include jquery for some time :)

Comment: Thanks for your work :) Even though I still don't understand why the original didn't work, it taught me cleaner methods when using KnockoutJS. So I'll accept it.

Comment: @CodeIntern any dynamically added HTML with knockout bindings **after `applyBindings()` is called**, will not work.

Comment: Oh i see. That clears a lot of doubts. Much appreciated.